# Android - Google Maps getting "Null Pointer Exception"

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I am trying to display multiple icons on a map using MapsForge. I have only been able to put 2 icons on the map in the correct GPS location without getting the error. When I try to add a 3rd icon, the app crashes and I get a null pointer exception. Also, the app doesn't download the tiles and gives me "MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80".

MapsForgeViewer:

```
public class MapsForgeViewer extends MapActivity implements OnClickListener {

private List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
private Drawable drawable1, drawable2;
private CustomItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay1, itemizedOverlay2, itemizedOverlay3;
private boolean isDisplayed = false;

private MapView mapView;
    private Button info;
    private Button roster;
    private Button schedule;
    private Button stats;
    private Button exit;

private OverlayItem [] pittIcon = {
        new OverlayItem( new GeoPoint(40.443061,-79.962273), "Pitt", "Panthers")       
    };
private OverlayItem [] cuseIcon = {
        new OverlayItem( new GeoPoint(43.037628,-76.137654), "Cuse", "Orangemen")
};
private OverlayItem [] lvilleIcon = {
        new OverlayItem( new GeoPoint(38.253153,-85.753847), "Louisville", "Cards")
};

    public void setOverlay1(){  
        int pittLength = pittIcon.length;
        // Create if it doesn't exist and display
        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();    
        drawable1 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pittspin); 
        itemizedOverlay1 = new CustomItemizedOverlay(drawable1); 

        for(int i=0; i<pittLength; i++){
            itemizedOverlay1.addOverlay(pittIcon[i]);
        }
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay1); 
        // Added symbols will be displayed when map is redrawn so force redraw now
        mapView.postInvalidate(); 
    }

    public void setOverlay2(){  
        // Create itemizedOverlay2 if it doesn't exist
        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();    
        drawable2 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.louispin);
        itemizedOverlay2 = new CustomItemizedOverlay(drawable2);     
        // Add items
        itemizedOverlay2.addOverlay(lvilleIcon[itemizedOverlay2.size()]);   
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay2);      
        mapView.postInvalidate();
    }

    public void setOverlay3(){  
        int cuseLength = cuseIcon.length;
        // Create itemizedOverlay2 if it doesn't exist and display all three items
        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();    
        Drawable drawable3 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cusepin); 
        itemizedOverlay3 = new CustomItemizedOverlay(drawable3); 
        // Display all three items at once
        for(int i=0; i<cuseLength; i++){
            itemizedOverlay3.addOverlay(cuseIcon[i]);
        }
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay3);
        isDisplayed = !isDisplayed;    
        // Added symbols will be displayed when map is redrawn so force redraw now
        mapView.postInvalidate(); 
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.map_view);

        info = (Button) findViewById(R.id.information);
        roster = (Button) findViewById(R.id.roster);
        schedule = (Button) findViewById(R.id.schedule);
        stats = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stats);
        exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
        info.setOnClickListener(this);
        roster.setOnClickListener(this);
        schedule.setOnClickListener(this);
        stats.setOnClickListener(this);
        exit.setOnClickListener(this);
        // end of mapView layout setup

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.setMapViewMode(MapViewMode.MAPNIK_TILE_DOWNLOAD);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setScaleBar(true);
        mapView.setClickable(true);
        mapView.getController().setZoom(5);
        setCenterlocation();
        // end of mapView setup

        setOverlay1(); 
        setOverlay2();
        //setOverlay3();
    }

public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case (R.id.information):
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Information.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        case (R.id.roster):
            showRoster(v);
            break;

        case (R.id.schedule):
            break;

        case (R.id.stats):
            break;

        // close the app
        case (R.id.exit):
            finish();
            break;
    }
}

public void showRoster(View v) {
    String url = "www.espn.com/roster";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
} 

@Override
// resumes the actions of the application on a pause
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
}

// perform any cleanup before the activity is destroyed 
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Cleanup();
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void Cleanup()
{    
    System.gc();
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();  
}

// sets the center of the screen on the map
protected void setCenterlocation()
{
    mapView.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(38.00, -100.00));
}
}
```

Here is the logcat after I try to add the 3rd:

```
02-21 22:31:17.031: I/Process(597): Sending signal. PID: 597 SIG: 9
02-21 22:32:47.502: D/dalvikvm(633): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 865 objects / 62432 bytes in 155ms
02-21 22:33:00.911: D/dalvikvm(633): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 296 objects / 15424 bytes in 199ms
02-21 22:33:02.051: D/dalvikvm(633): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 411 objects / 23800 bytes in 95ms
02-21 22:33:02.201: D/dalvikvm(633): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 102 objects / 4240 bytes in 104ms
02-21 22:33:03.641: D/dalvikvm(633): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5686 objects / 1276552 bytes in 142ms
02-21 22:33:04.351: D/dalvikvm(633): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 4507 objects / 992040 bytes in 126ms
02-21 22:33:05.092: D/dalvikvm(633): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 510 objects / 25744 bytes in 128ms
02-21 22:33:05.532: D/dalvikvm(633): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 83 objects / 3840 bytes in 243ms
02-21 22:33:05.732: D/dalvikvm(633): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 3 objects / 80 bytes in 181ms
02-21 22:33:06.262: D/dalvikvm(633): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 65 objects / 2504 bytes in 183ms
02-21 22:33:06.554: D/dalvikvm(633): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 8 objects / 432 bytes in 289ms
02-21 22:33:26.285: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:33:26.291: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:33:26.341: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:33:26.374: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:33:26.393: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:33:26.421: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:33:26.443: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:33:26.451: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:33:26.471: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:33:26.471: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:33:26.491: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:33:26.511: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:33:26.531: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:33:26.541: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:33:26.552: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:33:26.561: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:33:26.572: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:33:26.592: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:33:26.592: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:33:26.611: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:33:26.622: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:33:26.633: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:33:26.641: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:33:26.661: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:33:26.661: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:33:26.681: D/osm(633): MapnikTileDownload: Host is unresolved: tile.openstreetmap.org:80
02-21 22:48:07.212: D/dalvikvm(667): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 892 objects / 63472 bytes in 326ms
02-21 22:48:15.462: D/dalvikvm(667): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 297 objects / 15424 bytes in 214ms
02-21 22:48:16.386: D/dalvikvm(667): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 412 objects / 23824 bytes in 79ms
02-21 22:48:16.511: D/dalvikvm(667): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 102 objects / 4240 bytes in 79ms
02-21 22:48:17.574: D/dalvikvm(667): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5685 objects / 1276512 bytes in 104ms
02-21 22:48:18.061: D/dalvikvm(667): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 4507 objects / 992144 bytes in 89ms
02-21 22:48:18.441: D/AndroidRuntime(667): Shutting down VM
02-21 22:48:18.441: W/dalvikvm(667): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
02-21 22:48:18.473: E/AndroidRuntime(667): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 22:48:18.473: E/AndroidRuntime(667): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ashworth.craig/uc.roadmap.MapsForgeViewer}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 22:48:18.473: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
02-21 22:48:18.473: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-21 22:48:18.473: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-21 22:48:18.473: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-21 22:48:18.473: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-21 22:48:18.473: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-21 22:48:18.473: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-21 22:48:18.473: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 22:48:18.473: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-21 22:48:18.473: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-21 22:48:18.473: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-21 22:48:18.473: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-21 22:48:18.473: E/AndroidRuntime(667): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 22:48:18.473: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at uc.roadmap.MapsForgeViewer.setOverlay3(MapsForgeViewer.java:105)
02-21 22:48:18.473: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at uc.roadmap.MapsForgeViewer.onCreate(MapsForgeViewer.java:185)
02-21 22:48:18.473: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-21 22:48:18.473: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
02-21 22:48:18.473: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: What makes setOverlay3 different than numbers 1 and 2? Also, it's pinpointing the NullPointer to line 105 - which one is that?

Comment: Line 105: itemizedOverlay3.removeItem(itemizedOverlay3.size()-1);

Comment: Aha, that helps! See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Line 105: itemizedOverlay3.removeItem(itemizedOverlay3.size()-1);

The only way a NPE could be generated here is if itemizedOverlay3 is null (since it's the only object). Consider your if-else statement: You initialize itemizedOverlay3 in the "if" portion, but what if the "else" is called instead? You're calling itemizedOverlay3, *but it hasn't been initialized*.

So that's your problem. Initialize it outside of the if-else statement so that it's a valid object in either case. (And do this for your other methods too to avoid this error from popping up in one of them.)

Comment: This fixed my null pointer exception. I changed my code to initialize them without using an if-else statement. Now I am getting errors my VM won't allocate enough bytes for me to do this. How can this be when it is 3 medium size images? I have tried increasing my heap in the .ini file but that was no help.

Comment: Without knowing how large these "medium" sized images are, I'd say you need to be using "small" images since the mapView is going to be drawing them multiple times, which multiplies the memory needed. Try using smaller test images and see if that solves it.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't initialize List mapOverlays

on setOverlay1 & setOverlay2

you should initialize list before `mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();`

`mapOverlays = new List<Overlay>();`

Comment: mapOverlays doesn't need to be initialized just to be set to the mapView object. It's unnecessary.